# ajax query changing object key value to index

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm working with a firebase DB which has multiple collections and, using the included code, am able to successfully return an array consisting of all attractions with an area_id matching the area_id of e.target.

HOWEVER, something in my code is changing the attraction.id (different key than area_id) to the object’s index in the array. So, id 1 becomes 0, 2 becomes 1, etc…

At first I thought it was happening in the Object.keys so I put a console log in right before it and the change was already there. So, I’m almost positive that it’s happening in the query. Any help is much appreciated.

```
const getAttractionsByArea = (area_id) => {
  let attractions = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax(`https://theme-park.firebaseio.com/attractions.json?orderBy="area_id"&equalTo=${area_id}`)
      .then((results) => {
        Object.keys(results).forEach((result) => {
          results[result].id = result;
          attractions.push(results[result]);
        });
        resolve(attractions);
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to that you are setting the id, of each individual record, to the current key index as you are looping.

Remember that Object.keys returns a array of strings equal to enumerable properties of that object, in your case an array. Meaning you will get back an array of indexes.

You have this line

results[result].id = result;

You are setting the id of each element to it's index, so if element from db id was 54 for example it is now being set to 1, if it's the second result in your collection.

I am not sure why you have that line there in the first place but try commenting out that line and seeing what you get.